# Не удаляется текст у backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift4, navigationbar

Последнее время (xcode 9.4) выявил несколько непонятных мне багов. 1-не удаляется текст в кнопке back Bar Button, 2- не добавляется тень для кнопки созданной программно, при запуске на симуляторе и девайсе тень отсутствует. Кто-нибудь с подобным сталкивался или нет?

удаление текста

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

   navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тень для кнопки во viewDidLoad

```
var button = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 80, height: 80)
    button.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 105/255, blue: 144/255, alpha: 1.0)
    button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"Gill Sans", size: 23)
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.height
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addList), for:.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы удалить/поменять текст кнопки "назад", пропишите нужное в `Storyboard`, в выделенном поле для ввода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для **предыдущего** контроллера. Либо так же в коде.

С тенью - такое только в 9.4?

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня это поле на всех контроллерах пустое, тк надо кнопку только со стрелочкой, без текста...  А с тенью появилось, как обновил xcode, раньше не было. Хотя может и не с этим связано

Comment: @ArturSkachkov  в том и проблема, что пустое. Поставьте пробел, к примеру. По тени нужно больше инфо

Comment: И пробел ставлю, и др слово ввожу, все равно не реагирует, не пусто и др слово не отображает. В вопрос добавил скрин с сториборда и полный код на  тень.

Comment: @ArturSkachkov а можете приложить пример проекта с этой проблемой? С тенью из-за 
    button.clipsToBounds = true, она должна быть false (по дефолту она уже false)

Comment: С тенью так и есть, нужен был false, эх... Спасибо. А по кнопке вот сборка https://yadi.sk/d/-aOmUOkK3YVB2W

Comment: @ArturSkachkov Все нормально убирается. Судя по скрину, Вы в текущем пытаетесь. Убирайте в предыдущем, с которого осуществляется переход

Comment: Да, убирал в текущем. Спасибо